# Constantly update UITextView while using app

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to update a UITextView every so often (say every second) but haven't managed to do it yet.
Basically I use a function that uses the GPS location and I would like the result to be displayed in this UITextView. Up til now I do it by manually pressing a button regularly but would like this feature to be done automatically.
Any ideas?
Cheers!!

Comment: `CLLocation(Manager)` can update the location permanently. You just need a timer to get the information periodically.

Comment: No need for a timer really, you can just initiate the update from `didUpdateLocations`

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes but `didUpdateLocations` might update the location more frequently than one second

Comment: Yes, but you can easily check the timestamp on the location update to filter updates if required.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I didn't explain properly. I already do use CLLocation but my function is called when I press a button. I want the function to be always on the background so that the text is updated.

Comment: My function: 
`func distanceToPoint(toPoint: OTRGeoPoint) -> Double {let startPoint = OTRGeoPoint(latitude: (locationManager.currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!,long‌​itude: (locationManger.currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!) let d = Double(startPoint.latitude)-Double(toPoint.latitude) return d}`

I call it using: `@IBAction func clicOnbDistance(sender : UIButton) {tDistance?.text = String(distancetoPoint(toPoint: toPoint))}` I would like the tDistance to be updated without having to press a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like :

```
func fireEvent(everySeconds time:Double, event:@escaping ()->Void){

    let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + time

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: {

        event()

        self.fireEvent(everySeconds: time, event: event)

    })

}
```

usage :

```
fireEvent(everySeconds: 1, event: {

            self.textView.text = "your new string"

})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error: "Expected declaration" after the second argument of fireEvent when the function is called...

Comment: I shared my code right below while commenting Lindemberg's answer. As for the error "Expected declaration" I copied/pasted yours right above (changing only the name of the textView)

Comment: Show me pls screen.

Comment: Sorry about my last message. I tried your method again. And it worked!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand when exactly you need to update your UITextView.
But, if you consider Architectural Pattern MVC, your GPSController should notify you view that contains the UITextView every time that the values change. If you post entire code maybe i can help more.

Comment: My function: `func distanceToPoint(toPoint: OTRGeoPoint) -> Double {let startPoint = OTRGeoPoint(latitude: (locationManager.currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!,longitude: (locationManger.currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!)
let d = Double(startPoint.latitude)-Double(toPoint.latitude)
return d}`

Comment: I call it using: `@IBAction func clicOnbDistance(sender : UIButton) {tDistance?.text = String(distancetoPoint(toPoint: toPoint))}` 
I would like to call it "constantly" if that makes sense